# Security definer not working inside instead of trigger?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a  PostgreSQL 9.5 database with:

- A table test.domain(int id, text value) that stores possible values for a field. This data is dynamic.
- A table test.table(id int, domainn text) which domainn field references to the test.domain table.
- A view test.view_domain which is a view of test.domain.

I have defined a INSTEAD of trigger with the security definer option on the view. This trigger updates the table test.domain. The problem is that despite this trigger is being executed as the user "system", the reference update on the table test.table is executed by the invoker user.

Here is an example where, if executed as postgres, I expect to get "user system" as error instead of "user postgres"

```
drop schema IF EXISTS test  cascade;
create schema test;


create function test.modified() returns trigger as
$$
BEGIN
    raise exception 'user %', ' '||current_user;
END
$$
language plpgsql;

set role system;

create function test.insert_with_system() returns trigger as
$$
DECLARE
 valor text;
BEGIN

    --raise exception 'user %', ' '||current_user;
    update test.domain set value =  ''||new.value where id =  new.id;

END
$$ language plpgsql security definer;

reset role;

CREATE table test.domain(

id int primary key,
value text unique
);

create view test.domain_view as select * from test.domain;

create table test.table(
id int primary key,
domainn text
);

alter table test.table add foreign key (domainn)
   references test.domain(value) on delete restrict on update cascade;

create trigger test_trigger before insert or update or delete on test.table
   for each row execute procedure test.modified();

create trigger instead_ins INSTEAD OF update or delete on test.domain_view 
   for each row execute procedure test.insert_with_system();


insert into test.domain(id, value) values(1,'one');

alter table test.table  DISABLE TRIGGER all;
insert into test.table(id, domainn) values (0,'one');
alter table test.table enable TRIGGER all;

update test.domain_view set value = 'two';
select * from test.table;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cascading update is always run in the security context of the owner of the referencing table (`test.table` in your example).

See `ri_PerformCheck` in `src/backend/utils/adt/ri_triggers.c`:

```c
/*
 * Use the query type code to determine whether the query is run against
 * the PK or FK table; we'll do the check as that table's owner
 */
if (qkey->constr_queryno <= RI_PLAN_LAST_ON_PK)
    query_rel = pk_rel;
else
    query_rel = fk_rel;

...

/* Switch to proper UID to perform check as */
GetUserIdAndSecContext(&save_userid, &save_sec_context);
SetUserIdAndSecContext(RelationGetForm(query_rel)->relowner,
                       save_sec_context | SECURITY_LOCAL_USERID_CHANGE |
                       SECURITY_NOFORCE_RLS);
```

I tried to follow the code to its origin, and the behavior seems to originate in commit [465cf168eb6151275016486fe2d2c629fed967ca](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commitdiff;h=465cf168eb6151275016486fe2d2c629fed967ca).

Searching the hackers archives for relevant discussions, I found [this](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/Pine.LNX.4.21.0009200033300.362-200000%40peter).

So, as far as I can say, the behavior tries to avoid the following:

- User `A` owns `atable` and grants `REFERENCES` on that table to user `B`.
- User `B` owns `btable` and adds a foreign key to `atable` with `ON UPDATE OR DELETE CASCADE`. User `A` has no permissions on `btable`.
- User `A` tries to update or delete a row in `atable` that would cascade to `btable` and fails with a “permission denied” error.

I personally am not certain if the present behavior is good or not, but I can see the point that it would be surprising for `A`' not to be able to modify a table she owns.